# Google Cloud Platform: Error waiting for task (attempt 1 of 10): rpc error: code = Canceled desc = context canceled

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

I'm running a VM on the GCP. The main specs of this machine (machine type: e2-custom-2-6144) are as follows: Microsoft Windows Server 2019 Datacenter, Intel Broadwell, 6GB RAM, and 50GB hard disk.

The purpose of this VM is to run some simple automated email notifications via python (PyCharm) at 8 am everyday. As the code is utilizing selenium library, I decided to open a Windows machine with the very minimum performance to run. (It was originally 3GM RAM, but upgraded based upon the machine configuration recommendation)

It has been running great for a few months, but suddenly got this log as shown below with a shutdown at around 4 AM, resulting in not performing the codes on PyCharm due to shutdown from some errors here. To be honest, I don't know anything about these errors here, but it seems the shutdown was initiated from this one--Error waiting for task (attempt 1 of 10): rpc error: code = Canceled desc = context canceled. But, just in case, I copied all logs from the console.

Hopefully, a guru who was in my shoes could give a piece of advice.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you know the cause of the CPU and disk spike at 3am and was it expected? Are there any errors in the System or Application event logs in the VM that you can post?

Comment: Not exactly. Totally don't know why there was a spike even before 4 am, which has no associated logs. The capture above shows all the available logs between 1 am and 7 am.

Comment: Unfortunately without more information you aren't going to be able to diagnose the problem. If you truly have no logging **inside** the VM then you're never going to know. All I can suggest is that you make sure your PyCharm process runs after an unexpected reboot.

Comment: Could you please then explain this prompt: Error waiting for task (attempt 1 of 10): rpc? Is it something to with the machine, network, or others?

Comment: From the minimal information provided all I can say is that **something** tried to connect to **something else** via remote procedure call (RPC) and failed. It planned to try another 9 times (attempt 1 of 10) but didn't for an unknown reason. This may be a **cause** of the reboot or simply a **symptom** caused by the OS rebooting. Expecting a more definitive answer than that is asking for miracles. In your shoes I would check if the VM has installed updates and rebooted (morning after Patch Tuesday), make sure your PyCharm job runs after a reboot and enable / get access to OS event logs.